# Absolute positioned elements have same width but look different

Tags: html, css

I have 3 absolute positioned elements within a container, each with a width of 1px. However, these elements do not look to be all the same size when rendered. Why is this?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
}

div > * {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#child1 {
  left: -15px;
}

#child2 {
  left: -21px;
}

#child3 {
  left: -27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qdohy3pb/1/)

Here is what I see in my browser (using Chrome 102.0.5005.115):

[image]

The second child does not seem to be the same width as the other children.

Comment: Looks like a common rendering bug, looks the complete opposite on Firefox. No way to fix, I don't think.

Comment: There's no proper explanation for this, but changing the properties of the 2nd and 3rd children works: ```#child2 {
  left: -22px;
}

#child3 {
  left: -30px;
}```
I just increased the width between children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug on your browser. For me, the code snippet works on Chrome(Version 103.0.5060.53), Firefox (Version 102.0), and Safari(Version 15.5).

I suggest updating Chrome from chrome://settings/help.